When is a stationary distribution equally distributed in a markov chain?
I am trying to understand when will a Markov Chain have a stationary distribution evenly split between all states, e.g. $\pi = (0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2)$
In general:
$$
\pi P = \pi
$$
$$
\pi_i = \frac{1}{n} \quad \text{for all } i = 1, 2, ..., n
$$
$$\pi = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n})$$
$$
(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n}) P = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n})
$$
As I understand, this can only happen if a Markov Chain is doubly stochastic (i.e. all rows and columns sum to $1$). I am trying to understand why this is.

Suppose I have a Markov chain with $n$ states and transition probability matrix $P = (p_{ij})$, where $p_{ij}$ is the probability of transitioning from state $i$ to state $j$:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for all } j = 1, 2, ..., n \quad \text{(column sum)}
$$
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n p_{ij} = 1 \quad \text{for all } i = 1, 2, ..., n \quad \text{(row sum)}
$$
If I write the basic definition (assuming $P$ is doubly stochastic)  $\pi P = \pi$ and I want to prove that $\pi = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n})$ is a stationary distribution.
I would need to show that:
$$(\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n}) P = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n})$$
If I compute the left side of this equation. The $j$-th element of $\pi P$ vector is:
$$(\pi P)_j = \sum_{i=1}^n \pi_i p_{ij} = \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{n} p_{ij} = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij}$$
Now, because $P$ is doubly stochastic, we know that $\sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} = 1$ for all $j$. Therefore:
$$(\pi P)_j = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n p_{ij} = \frac{1}{n} \cdot 1 = \frac{1}{n}$$
This is true for all $j$, so we have shown that:
$$\pi P = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n}) = \pi$$
Thus, $\pi = (\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n}, ..., \frac{1}{n})$ is a stationary distribution when $P$ is doubly stochastic.

Is my work correct? Or is this kind of circular proof not acceptable?

Looks fine. Why do you think it is a circular proof?
